# Execution of Any() clause against IQueryable object

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I have an object IQueryable that represent some query over my db-model.
Now i need to do some validation to that IQeryable and return back the object in that way

```
 private IQuerable<myTableType> ValidateQery ( IQuerable<myTableType> query , string user )
 {
           return query.Where ( x => db.tblUsers.Where( y => y.User == user && y.Privilege >= x.PrivilegeRequired).Any() )
 }
```

Now what i would like to understand is if the Any() clause is executed immidiatly or if it generate T-SQL that will be merged with previous.
I ask that because i wuold avoid to execute a query against the db in that moment.

Edit :
Thanks for the advice of 'using' clause, it was a fault that i made now (writing this code example) because i am not able to test code now (i have no visual studio on my machine in this moment) but my problem in general was about that situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Any` is inside of a lambda in `Queryable.Where`, and as such is not executed as C# code and is instead translated into an `Expression` and passed to the query provider when the `IQueryable` returned from `Where` is iterated.

On a site node, you're disposing of the context before the `IQueryable` you return can ever be iterated, so it'll always fail when you do iterate it.

Comment: Thanks you have clarify my idea of how IQeryable object is executed.

Comment: @Servy I have to ask, considering that he is using 'db' as his context, and it's not flagging it as an error, and he isn't passing it in, one could assume that db is being declared as a module level/class level variable.  In that case, the context may or may not be disposed of before execution, correct?

Comment: @RobertMcKee He edited the code during the grace period.

Answer (score 3):

It's part of the query - it's within a `Where` clause.

So no, it won't be executed immediately. Having said that, you appear to be closing the context that the query uses, so I suspect that by the time it *is* used, it'll be broken...